# Exporting history feed in Gowalla

Tags: foursquare, gowalla

In Fourquare the [History](http://foursquare.com/history) option is given to get my trip history in RSS format.

Is there a way to do this in Gowalla (or at least export my Stamp or Passport history) ?

Comment: Gowalla, as a service, was shut down on March 11, 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gowalla have an atom feed for your checkins, would this be enough for you ?

Example: http://gowalla.com/users/marcroberts/checkins.atom

There is also more available through their API - http://gowalla.com/api/explorer

Comment: Yes that would work , why do they not have it as a feature in the settings tab ?